# Is it necessary to open ports 2377, 7946, 4789 to create a docker swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

According to [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/#the-ip-address-of-the-manager-machine) link:

> The following ports must be available. On some systems, these ports
>   are open by default.
>
> TCP port 2377 for cluster management communications 
>   TCP and UDP port
>   7946 for communication among nodes UDP port 4789 for overlay network
>   traffic If you plan on creating an overlay network with encryption
>   (--opt encrypted), you also need to ensure ip protocol 50 (ESP)
>   traffic is allowed

but I was able to create a swarm and join nodes to it without opening above ports and I don't think they are open by default on my network. So I am trying to understand if above documentation is incorrect?

```
siddjain@goldenrwr-ca0:~$ docker node ls
ID                            HOSTNAME             STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION
ub40pn2najtvkcnhewoilqboi *   goldenrwr-ca0        Ready               Active              Leader              18.06.1-ce
quyiss2gl6036x6z4znagr6zl     goldenrwr-orderer0   Ready               Active                                  18.06.1-ce
y2kqrqoeaipjkflmyg1xq1pvu     goldenrwr-peer0      Ready               Active                                  18.06.1-ce
2hnhwb06dkbhlilpcuqnnbboc     goldenrwr-peer1      Ready               Active                                  18.06.1-ce
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question is **Yes**. Those ports are needed by docker to work. We can verify this by running `netstat -tuplen` on the nodes to see what ports are being used.

E.g., on a master node I see this:

```
$ netstat -tuplen
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      101        15135221   -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          25361290   -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::2377                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          1423965    -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::7946                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          1423980    -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          25361301   -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           101        15135220   -                   
udp        0      0 10.2.0.4:68             0.0.0.0:*                           100        15135187   -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4789            0.0.0.0:*                           0          1424168    -                   
udp6       0      0 :::7946                 :::*                                0          1423981    -
```

on a worker node I see this:

```
$ netstat -tuplen
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      101        234169     -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          8088243    -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::7946                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          61278      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          8088254    -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           101        234168     -                   
udp        0      0 10.2.0.7:68             0.0.0.0:*                           100        234114     -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4789            0.0.0.0:*                           0          61504      -                   
udp6       0      0 :::7946                 :::*                                0          61279      -
```

Aside: Somehow it works even though I see below config denying all inbound network traffic in azure

[image]

Answer (score 6):

2377/tcp must be open between the nodes (this doesn't mean open to external traffic) to get to this point. If you have issues with overlay networking, e.g. containers not able to connect to each other, or accessing an ingress published port only works when you access the same node where the container happens to be running, then the issue is most likely the other ports not being open.

Comment: My question is that I have not opened the ports in question and don't see any issues with overlay networking. I am able to ping other nodes. So I'd like to understand how is this possible if the docs say those ports need to be opened.

Comment: The ports need to be opened between the nodes. If you didn't open them, then they were already opened, or no admin ever configured a firewall between the nodes.

Comment: Thanks - perhaps there is no firewall between the nodes. How can I verify that?

Comment: @morpheus it sounds like you already have. `tcpdump`, `nmap`, and netcat would be a few tools I often use to debug network connectivity.